# DXFilter is somehow still working in IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

This standalone example has a DXFilter to render a gradient, it renders in quirks mode. IE10 has 'show legacy filters' set to off, I see it in the 'internet' zone. I still see the gradient?

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

"DirectX-based Filters and Transitions (DX filters) are obsolete in Internet Explorer 10 for webpages in the Internet Zone. "

Why does this work?

```
<!-- Comment before Doctype to force quirks mode in IE6/7 -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=5">
</head>

<style type="text/css" >
.SomeDiv
{
WIDTH: 50px;
HEIGHT: 50px;
FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#00ff00', EndColorStr='#ff0000');
}
</style>


<div class='SomeDiv'>
Hi
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Removed my answer, was running on `http://localhost/`. Regardless, if you observe different behaviour than documented, the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Obsolete does not mean removed. In this case, there are two reasons:

- The comment before the doctype triggers IE5 quirksmode
- The site is running in the Intranet Zone or Trusted Sites Zone

If it is inconsistently appearing in the Internet Zone, there are two reasons:

> End-users can change these settings (for these document modes only) by using Internet Options to change the security settings for the zone in question. Administrators can also use Group Policy.

Comment: It was in the internet zone. We've also noticed it seems to be inconsistent, sometimes working sometimes not.